# drools rule to relate two facts without eval

Tags: drools

So I'm still relatively new to drools. I know how to use eval to compare facts, but I'm under the impression I should be able to write the rules without the eval statement. I was hoping to get some help understanding how I would do so in the following situation?

I have a fact that a supervisor is being requested for a given user's email address:

```
declare SupervisorRequested
    email : String
end
```

and a map from users to their supervisor (potentially -- some users  have no supervisors)

```
// Map<String, User>
knowledgeResources.add(supervisors);
```

And so the rule I have written is

```
rule "Supervisor Inclusion Requested"
    when
        request : SupervisorRequested()
        supervisors : Map()
        eval(supervisors.get(request.email) != null)
    then
        ...
end
```

So, the question is, how could I write this without resorting to using eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below rule will fire for all instances where the map (assumed to be in working memory) contains a user mapped to the email and will not fire if `$supervisors.get($email)` returns null. One of the biggest conveniences of working with Drools in MVEL is that we should rarely have to do null checks.

```
rule "Supervisor Inclusion Requested"
    when
        $request : SupervisorRequested($email: email)
        $supervisors: Map()
        $supervisorWithEmail : User() from $supervisors.get($email)
    then
        ...
end
```

Hope that helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below rule to get the desired condition check :

```
rule "Supervisor Inclusion Requested"
when
    request : SupervisorRequested()
    map : HashMap(this.get(request.getEmail())  != null)
then
    // .............
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `this` syntax since it's an alias for `get(...)`. For example: `Map( $value: this["foo"])` is functionally the same as `$value = map.get("foo")`.

Keeping that in mind, you can write your rule like:

```
rule "Supervisor Inclusion Requested"
when
  SupervisorRequested( $email: email ) // gets the email 
  Map( this[$email] != null ) // checks that the map contains the email
then
 // omitted
end
```